# Kernel appears to have died, IT WILL RESTART AUTOMATICALLY - JUPYTER NOTEBOOK

Tags: python, kernel, jupyter

I've been trying this code for a while and I am getting the above mentioned error. I've tried to upgrade the numby. Everything is fine but still I get the error.

I've attached the code here:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


img = cv2.imread('D:\motog5plus camera\IMG_20180617_120221162.jpg')
mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2],np.uint8)

bgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)
fgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)

rect = (50,50,450,290)
cv2.grabCut(img,mask,rect,bgdModel,fgdModel,5,cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)

mask2 = np.where((mask==2)|(mask==0),0,1).astype('uint8')
img = img*mask2[:,:,np.newaxis]

plt.imshow(img),plt.colorbar(),plt.show()
```

Comment: Please format the code in your question such that it is easier readable. Next, try to insert segments of the code in different Jupyter Notebook Cells, such that you can execute each segment individually. This way you can tell which segment of the code causes the Kernel restart. This would be an important information that you can include in your question.

Comment: thanks johannmik, i executed the code in each segment and i got the error at reading the image. the image resolution was high, so i compressed and debugged again. it worked perfectly.